# App crashing in splash screen in iPhone 3G second time when i open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an application for both iphone 3G and iPhone4,if i test my app in iPhone 4 everything works fine but if i test my app in iPhone 3G app works fine but if i click home button of my iPhone and soon if i click my app icon only splash screen shown and while showing splash screen only it is crashing if i wait for about 30 seconds after i close it is working, since in iPhone 4 it is having multitasking and more memory if i do the same process the app is not crashing.
I don't know what is the problem is this the problem of my code? or iPhone? or i need to handle any of appdelegate methods like

1.applicationDidBecomeActive:
2.applicationWillResignActive:
3.applicationDidEnterBackground:
4.applicationWillEnterForeground:
5.applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Any help is appreciated in advance.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not doing any heavy processing in the following methods

1. applicationDidBecomeActive
2. applicationDidFinishLaunching
3. applicationWillEnterForeground

iOS will terminate your application if its taking time in the above methods, so keep these methods clean and do the processing in your RootViewController etc

Answer (score 0):

I advise you using breakpoints during the following methods to know exactly what is happening in your program:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationDidFinishLaunching
viewDidUnload (and all previous methods just before the unloading of the 
last view before you press your home button)
Allover your MainDelegate
```

Try making the application run in the background and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iPhone 3G is slower it is still closing your app when you try to start it again.
That it is not closed directly could be because you are doing some thing that take a lite longer then you would expect.

It is not really crashing, what you see it just the app closing it self. that is why if you try it after some second it will work.

Mainly these could be `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`.

Just make sure you exit you app as some a posible, by for example save any data before the user will close the app.